# vb.net arraylist of objects

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I am trying to create an arraylist of objects, and everything is working fine except that the value of all 11 objects are the same.  I've have tried multiple ways of writing the code, but I get the same outcome everytime.

arrFullProdList collects the name of all the products in the database.  This is working properly.  arrProducts is where I am having the issue with all the objects being the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Declared

```
Private objReader As SqlDataReader
Private objProducts As New CProducts
Private arrFullProdList As ArrayList = New ArrayList
Public arrProdcuts As ArrayList = New ArrayList
```

class CProduct

```
Public Class CProduct

    Private _pstrProdId As String
    Private _pstrProdDesc As String
    Private _psngWhCost As Single
    Private _psngRetPrice As Single
    Private _pblnTaxable As Boolean
    Private _isNewProd As Boolean

    Public Sub New()

        '_pstrProdId = ""
        '_pstrProdDesc = ""
        '_psngWhCost = 0
        '_psngRetPrice = 0
        '_pblnTaxable = False
        '_isNewProd = False
    End Sub

    Public Property strProdId() As String
        Get
            Return _pstrProdId
        End Get
        Set(strVal As String)
            _pstrProdId = strVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property strProdDesc() As String
        Get
            Return _pstrProdDesc
        End Get
        Set(strVal As String)
            _pstrProdDesc = strVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property sngWhCost() As Single
        Get
            Return _psngWhCost
        End Get
        Set(sngVal As Single)
            _psngWhCost = sngVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property sngRetPrice() As Single
        Get
            Return _psngRetPrice
        End Get
        Set(sngVal As Single)
            _psngRetPrice = sngVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property blnTaxable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _pblnTaxable
        End Get
        Set(blnVal As Boolean)
            _pblnTaxable = blnVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IsNewProd() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isNewProd
        End Get
        Set(blnVal As Boolean)
            _isNewProd = blnVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property GetSaveParameters() As ArrayList
        Get
            Dim paramList As New ArrayList
            paramList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("ProdId", _pstrProdId))
            paramList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("ProdDesc", _pstrProdDesc))
            paramList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("WhCost", _psngWhCost))
            paramList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("RetPrice", _psngRetPrice))
            paramList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("Taxable", _pblnTaxable))
            Return paramList
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Save() As Integer
        'return -1 if the ID already exists and we can't create a new record
        If _isNewProd Then
            Dim strRes As String = myDB.GetSingleValueFromSP("sp_CheckProdIDExists", _
                                                             New SqlClient.SqlParameter("ProdId", _pstrProdId))
            If Not strRes = 0 Then
                Return -1 'ID NOT unique!!
            End If
        End If
        'if not a new member or it is new and is unique, then do the save (update or insert)
        Return myDB.ExecSP("sp_SaveProduct", GetSaveParameters)
    End Function


End Class
```

class CProducts

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class CProducts

    'This class represents the Members table and the associated business rules
    Private _Product As CProduct
    'constructor
    Public Sub New()
        'instantiate the CMember object
        _Product = New CProduct
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentObject() As CProduct
        Get
            Return _Product
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub Clear()
        _Product = New CProduct
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateNewProduct() 'call me when you are clearing the screen to create a new member
        Clear()
        _Product.IsNewProd = True
    End Sub

    Public Function Save() As Integer
        Return _Product.Save
    End Function

    Public Function GetProductList() As SqlDataReader
        Return myDB.GetDataReaderBySP("dbo.sp_GetProductList")
    End Function

    Public Function GetProducIdList() As SqlDataReader
        Return myDB.GetDataReaderBySP("dbo.sp_GetProductIdList")
    End Function

    Public Function GetProductByName(strProdDesc As String) As CProduct
        Dim params As New ArrayList
        Dim param1 As New SqlParameter("proddesc", strProdDesc)
        params.Add(param1)
        FillObject(myDB.GetDataReaderBySP("dbo.sp_GetProductByName", params))
        Return _Product
    End Function


    Public Function GetProductById(strProdId As String) As CProduct
        Dim aParam As New SqlParameter("ProdId", strProdId)
        FillObject(myDB.GetDataReaderBySP("dbo.sp_GetProductByID", aParam))
        Return _Product
    End Function


    Public Function FillObject(sqlDR As SqlDataReader) As CProduct
        Using sqlDR
            If sqlDR.Read Then
                With _Product
                    .strProdId = sqlDR.Item("ProdId") & ""
                    .strProdDesc = sqlDR.Item("ProdDesc") & ""
                    .sngWhCost = sqlDR.Item("WhCost") & ""
                    .sngRetPrice = sqlDR.Item("RetPrice") & ""
                    .blnTaxable = sqlDR.Item("Taxable") & ""
                End With
            Else
                'failed for some reason
            End If
        End Using
        Return _Product
    End Function

    '----------Start Alex's Code---------
    Public Function GetProductByDesc(strProdDesc As String) As SqlDataReader
        Dim aParam As New SqlParameter("ProdDesc", strProdDesc)
        Return myDB.GetDataReaderBySP("dbo.sp_GetProductByDesc", aParam)
    End Function
End Class
```

main

```
Private Sub LoadProducts()
    arrProdcuts.Clear()
    objReader = objProducts.GetProductByDesc(txtSearch.Text)
    While objReader.Read
        arrFullProdList.Add(objReader.Item("prodDesc"))
    End While
    objReader.Close()

    For i = 0 To arrFullProdList.Count - 1
        Dim aNewProd As CProduct
        aNewProd = objProducts.GetProductByName(arrFullProdList.Item(i).ToString)
        arrProdcuts.Add(aNewProd)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What are `objReader`, `objProducts`, `GetProductByDesc`, `CProduct`? Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm confused by the line "arrProdcuts.Add...". What datatype is arrProdcuts? I don't see an Add method in your code. It seems like it is CProducts, because of the Clear, but I don't see an Add.

Comment: The core of your problem is that you are adding a reference to the same object over and over again to the list, but we need more code to see where that is exactly happening.

Comment: Jeremy,  thanks for the the comment.  What other code do you need to see?  arrProducts is an arraylist and so is arrFullProdList.  arrFullProdList collects only the name of each product.  Then I use a loop to go through the database to collect an object of type CProduct and add each one to the arrProducts.

Comment: If you follow the path of the _Product variable, it never gets set to a "New" instance in between populations of data so what you are doing is adding the same instance over and over into the list, so each element in the list is pointing to the same place in memory.